# AWS Cognito Authentication Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to follow the [docs](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js#usage) for authenticating a user via my login form. Use case 4 says it's for authenticating a user, but i'm still getting the error that my user is unauthenticated so i'm confused.

I can successfully call the `authenticateUser` function and get a token and redirect to a different page, but then when that page calls `getUserAttributes` I get the error that the user is not logged in.

login.vue

```
const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(cognitoConfig)

  const authenticationData = {
    Username: this.username,
    Password: this.password
  }

  const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData)

  const userData = {
    Username: this.username,
    Pool: userPool
  }
  const user = new CognitoUser(userData)
  const self = this

  user.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: result => {
      const token = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()
      console.log('token = ', token)
      self.$store.commit('user/SET_USERNAME', self.username)
      self.$router.push('/dashboard')
    },
    onFailure: err => {
      console.log('err = ', err)
    }
  })
```

dashboard.vue

```
const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(cognitoConfig)
const userData = {
  Username: this.user.username,
  Pool: userPool
}

console.log('userData = ', userData)

const user = new CognitoUser(userData)
user.getUserAttributes((err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('getUserAttributes err = ', err)
    alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err))
    return
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    console.log('attribute ' + result[i].getName() + ' has value ' + result[i].getValue())
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In dashboard.vue you are creating a new user instance, that user, is not authenticated. Try getUserAttributes just after autheticateUser.

The reason is, when you call authenticateUser, after success, some properties are settled to the calling user instance, token, signature, etc...

Then when you call another method, just like getUserAttributes, it uses that info.

Your code in dashboard.vue fails because at the moment you call the method, the user **instance** is not authenticated, as you are able to read from the error message.

You need authenticate ALL user INSTANCEs.